# Анимация переворота карты

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

Делаю простенькую карточную игру. Разложено несколько карт и я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на любую из них она переворачивалась с использованием анимации.

Подскажите, не могу понять, какую анимацию и как правильно использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использую вот такой класс:

```
public class FlipAnimation implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    private Animation animation1;
    private Animation animation2;
    private boolean isBackOfCardShowing = true;
    private ImageView img;
    private Context ctx;
    private FlipEnd flipped;
    Card card;

    public interface FlipEnd {
        void flipEnd(ImageView img, Card card);
    }

    FlipAnimation(Context ctx, ImageView img, Card card) {
        this.img = img;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.card = card;
        flipped = (FlipEnd) ctx;
        animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.flip_to_middle);
        animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
        animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.flip_from_middle);
        animation2.setAnimationListener(this);

        img.clearAnimation();
        img.setAnimation(animation1);
        img.startAnimation(animation1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if (animation == animation1) {
            if (isBackOfCardShowing) {    
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_face);
                flipped.flipEnd(img,card);
            } else {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);
            }
            img.clearAnimation();
            img.setAnimation(animation2);
            img.startAnimation(animation2);
        } else {
            isBackOfCardShowing = !isBackOfCardShowing;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
}
```

Тут еще сразу добавлен интерфэйс, чтобы отслеживать, когда и какая карта перевернулась. Кастомизируйте его, как хотите.

`R.anim.flip_to_middle.xml` :

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

`flip_from_middle.xml`:

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="250" />
```

Вызывать там, где надо: `new FlipAnimation(YourActivity.this, cardImage);`

Попробуйте, эффект будет как будто переворачивается карта :)

Comment: а как использовать интерфэйс?

Comment: @Алекс, просто имплементируйте его в вашу активность (`YourActivity implements FlipAnimation.FlipEnd`) и добавьте метод  `void flipEnd(ImageView img, Card card){...}`

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Все работает!